# How can i add custom field to admin panel for User Model

Tags: django

How can I add a custom field for the User Model to the admin page?

I have defined a Char field to abstract User. Although I can see this field in the database, I can't see it in the Django admin panel. I created a Meta class and wrote my field, but it's still invisible on the admin panel.

This issue is not happening with my custom models, only with Django's User model. Can anybody tell me why this is happening and what I should do?

Comment: Please provide your code for your admin class.

Answer (score 1):

Do such a thing, it may work.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (
            "Personal info",
            {
                "fields": (
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name",
                    "email",
                    "phone",
                    "personnel_code",
                    "role",
                    "national_code",
                    "branch",
                    "manager",
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            "Permissions",
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    # "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                )
            },
        ),
        ("Important dates", {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ("wide",),
                "fields": ("username", "password1", "password2"),
            },
        ),
        (
            "Personal info",
            {
                "fields": (
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name",
                    "email",
                    "phone",
                    "personnel_code",
                    "role",
                    "national_code",
                    "branch",
                    "manager",
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            "Permissions",
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    # "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                )
            },
        ),
    )
```

You can place your field anywhere you want.

I hope it works for you.